# Настройки гема для рельсов Chartkick

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-chart

Существует гем для рельсов Chartkick. Знает ли кто-нибудь, как в Bar Charts поставить значения над или рядом со столбцами и как в Pie Charts сменить цвет текста в поле диаграммы?